# Reduce query time by adding multiple indexes on nodes - Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, apache-kafka, cypher, nodes

I have an application which streams Twitter data and sends it to two Kafka topics. These Kafka topics are read by two different machines, which send the data to a Neo4j database (placed on one of the two machines).

Some of the data-inserting queries have a `MERGE` clause, that makes queries very slow while data grows. Now, I'm trying to reduce query time.

Is it a good practice to add multiple indexes on nodes (they already got one) in order to have smaller pattern of nodes each time a `MERGE` is performed? Has this got someway sense? Below an example of a query:

```
MERGE (t:Tweet{tweet_id:{tweet_id}})
SET t.text={text}, t.language={language}, 
t.created_at={created_at}, t.retweetcount={retweetcount}, 
t.likecount={likecount}, t.location={location}
```

Query plan:

[image]

Comment: Can give your `MERGE` query and the its `EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: I added an example of query @logisima

Comment: And you have a unique constraint on `:Tweet tweet_id` ?
More over, on your query why are you using the `SET` command, a `ON CREATE SET` is not enough ?

Comment: No, I had it in a previous version of my application, but it used to slow queries even more. So I removed it because basically I'll never get two tweets with identical ID

Comment: Unfortunately it's not enough, because sometimes I have retweets which force me to update some information of the tweet (favorite_count, retweet_count)

Comment: Without an `index` or a `constraint` on the property `tweet_id` for  node `Tweet` the `MERGE` will be really slow. Can you post the query plan of the query ?
For the second part, if you know that when a tweet already exist you will only update the favorite + retweet count, you should use the pattern `MERGE (..)  ON CREATE SET ... ON MATCH SET ...`

Comment: Regarding the first part: I don't know what you mean with query plan.
Second part: thanks for the hint. I thought that the problem was to find the matching nodes rather than editing the properties. What do you think about it? Am I gonna improve the queries by using `CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET` ?

Comment: In the browser if you prefix your query with `EXPLAIN ` Neo4j will give you the query plan of the query. Can you copy/paste here the image ?

Comment: @logisima I edited the question with the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the query plan, you should create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`on the field `tweet_id` for the label `Tweet` :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Tweet) ASSERT n.tweet_id IS UNIQUE
```

So instead of performing a `NodeByLabelScan` plus a `Filter`, you will do a `NodeUniqueIndexSeek` witch is **really better**.

Moreover, less work you give to the database, better the performances are :)

So if you only have to update the field `favorite_count`& `retweet_count` when the node is already there, you should use the sub-commands `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET` of `MERGE` like this :

```
MERGE (t:Tweet{tweet_id:{tweet_id}})
  ON CREATE SET 
    t.text={text}, 
    t.language={language}, 
    t.created_at={created_at}, 
    t.retweetcount={retweetcount}, 
    t.likecount={likecount}, 
    t.location={location}
  ON MATCH SET 
    t.retweetcount={retweetcount}, 
    t.likecount={likecount}
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know if it went better. Thank you so much.